# Image Processing(oblique image)

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I hope you can give me some suggestions. I want to semantically segment the cyanobacteria image of the lake, and hope to calculate the cyanobacteria area in the image. How to preprocess the image due to the existence of a certain angle?It is not vertical. Make it more accurate to calculate the actual area through pixels. The image is as follows.

[image: 3/4 angled camera view of cyanobacteria in a water stream]

Comment: i don't get what you are looking for... how to rotate an image by an angle?

Comment: For a vertical picture, the actual size can be calculated accurately according to the pixel and proportion, but the image is not taken vertically, so how to deal with the picture? Or projected into a vertical picture.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make calibrated measurements (in true units of area) without knowing the scaling factors. So you should let a calibration target float on the water, wholly in the field of view*.

If the viewing distance is sufficiently large that the perspective effect can be neglected, the transformation is affine and it suffices to take the ratio of the apparent area of the cyanobacteria (in pixels) over the apparent area of the target (in pixels), times the true area of the target**.

If the perspective is strong, the transformation is an homography, and things get a little more complicated. From four points of the target (say corners), you can obtain the coefficients of the homography that maps the viewed points to undistorded space. Then you need to undistort the cyanobacteria area outline (as a polygon) and you can compute its area by the shoelace formula.

You can also completely straighten the image before segmentation, though this is not really necessary.

---

*You could think of obtaining the scaling factors by knowing viewing angles and distance, but that method will be unpractical to use in the field.

**Take a picture of a large square. If it appears like a parallelogram, you are good. If like a general quadrilateral, perspective must be corrected.